# Which of "calf's-foot jelly" and "calves'-foot jelly" is appropriate?

Tags: word-choice

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to write “calf's liver”  on menu](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/42597/how-to-write-calfs-liver-on-menu)

I'm trying to find out which of the terms *calf's-foot jelly* and  *calves'-foot jelly* is more appropriate for referring to this [aspic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspic)-like comestible in conversation, but haven't found any definitive answer; [ngrams](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=calf%27s+foot+jelly%2Ccalves+%27+foot+jelly%2Ccalves%27+feet+jelly&year_start=1790&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=3) shows similar frequency of use for both terms. Any advice? [image: ngram for calf's foot jelly,calves' foot jelly,calves' feet jelly]

*Edit:* I added suggested term *calves'-feet jelly* to the ngrams search.  For brief intervals ca. 1810, 1840, and 1900, it was dominant, but usually one of the other two terms has prevailed in frequency.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - Good find; I overlooked that question

Comment: It was lucky OP here asked about "calf". I knew it had come up before, but for some reason I remembered it as being about *pig's trotters*. We'll be ready now when someone asks about [Larks' Tongues In Aspic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Larks'_Tongues_in_Aspic). Which I still remember as *tongue*, not *tongues*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless specifically made from conjoined twin calves sharing the same foot, it would be *calf's-foot jelly*, since the possessive for multiple calves would otherwise imply multiple feet.

*Calves'-**feet** jelly* would be a more logical alternative, but I still lean toward *calf's-foot*. Jams and jellies tend to be named in the singular, not in the plural. Peach preserves, not peaches preserves. Strawberry jam, not strawberries jam. Orange marmalade, grape jelly, etc.

So by extension, *calf's-foot jelly*.

[Multiple](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/calf-s-foot-jelly) [dictionaries](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/calf%27s-foot+jelly) [concur.](http://www.epicurious.com/tools/fooddictionary/entry/?id=1660)