# Using an apostrophe on wedding invitation

Tags: punctuation, possessives, apostrophe, attributive-nouns

I am designing an RSVP, in which I give my guests the option of choosing their meal preference. I have a column for ticking the option of a kid's meal, then at the bottom I have a key for all of the meals.

My question is:
If my key is talking about meals in general should it be written "kids' meal"?
Then should the tick box be labelled "kid's meal", as it is one person indicating the meal for their one child?

If this is correct, is it strange to have it written differently on the same invitation? Is there a way I can write both of them the same way that would be correct?

I don't want to get this wrong as I am a teacher and I am inviting a whole load of teachers to my wedding! :)

Many thanks

(Hope I've explained this correctly - I've attached a picture for reference)
[image]

Comment: You could leave it as: *kids meal* as in *men shoes*. The first noun acts "like" an adjective, it's called an *adjunct noun*. Otherwise, if the noun is regular and plural the apostrophe comes after the -s. For example: *The kids' teacher is getting married.* But *The men's shoes were laid outside*

Comment: Related [a noun adjunct the possessive case](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/87591/a-noun-adjunct-the-possessive-case) and [Where should the apostrophe be placed in “Goats Milk”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/154210/where-should-the-apostrophe-be-placed-in-goats-milk)

Comment: @Mari-Lou A The modern style is 'mens shoes'. The taboo apostropheless _mens_ has been around for many years now in _working mens clubs_. As shown [here](http://search.myway.com/search/GGmain.jhtml?searchfor=men+shoes&st=tab&ptb=0929934B-6CAB-4AB8-B579-9FED6D5F249D&p2=%5EBME%5Ehps010%5ES11985%5Egb&si=CLGyubDM3cMCFQMewwodAyAAfA&n=781AC8A2&tpr=hpsb&trs=hps).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth yes, you're right (as nearly always :)) although my last sentence is grammatical. Perhaps not the best example I could have given.

Comment: Although my wife says my sense of style is ... er ... absent. Nice to see the kids getting a square meal.

Comment: `@Mari-LouA` @EdwinAshworth - 1) A case of forcing square bread into round holes? 2) We also have the parallel forms *men's wear* and *menswear*.

Comment: Signs on restrooms:  Mens.....Womens. (at least it didn't say "menses"!)

Comment: @ErikKowal well, I did admit that the example I chose was not the "happiest". So let's change that to: **student lockers**, **students locker** and  **students' lockers**, all three are acceptable, although they have slightly different meanings.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. There was a reply in "Where should the apostrophe be placed in “Goats Milk”?" which made me think about swapping kid's/kids' to child's/children's. I think I'll do that as it's more obvious that I'm making the distinction between singular and plural, rather than a typo! 

...and don't worry - I'm not feeding the children a square! It's just design work in progress :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should leave it as you have it. You have defensible reasons. If anyone claims it's a typo you can put them in their place with the same reasoning you have given here. 
And good for you for thinking about it.